# My mui autocomplete multiselect input base component is being rendered behind other components on the page

Tags: material-ui

I am using mui's autocomplete multiselect component and as the input base grows with the chip labels they eventually end up behind the other components on the page. Here is how it looks currently [image]

I have tried setting the max height on the input component, changing its display type etc but  nothing seems to be working. I want that as the component grows the other components below are pushed down as well.

Comment: Please share your component code implementation in the question to debug it. Or share a codesandbox if possible.